# SQL server User Defined Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a User Defined Cursor, but I get the following error,

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

I am using AdventureWorks2008r2

This is my code ;

```
USE AdventureWorks2008r2
GO

DECLARE
    -- LOCAL VARIABLEs
    @OrderId INT,
    @status TINYINT

--declare the cursor 
DECLARE mynamelist CURSOR STATIC
FOR
SELECT Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID, Sales.SalesOrderHeader.STATUS
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader;

OPEN mynamelist;

FETCH NEXT
FROM mynamelist
INTO @status,
    @OrderId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    IF @status = 1
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT
        FROM mynamelist
        INTO @status,@OrderId

        PRINT 'Order Number:' + CAST(@OrderId AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'Status:Approved';
    END;
    ELSE IF @status = 3
        PRINT 'Order Number:' + CAST(@OrderId AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'Status:Backordered';
    ELSE IF @status = 4
        PRINT 'Order Number:' + CAST(@OrderId AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'Status:Rejected';
    ELSE IF @status = 5
        PRINT 'Order Number:' + CAST(@OrderId AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'Status:Shipped';
    ELSE
        PRINT 'Order Number:' + CAST(@OrderId AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'Status:Cancelled';
    END;

CLOSE nynamelist;

DEALLOCATE mynamelist;
```

How can I fix this error

Comment: missing a semicolon `;` before `open mynamelist;`? Meaning `...FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader;`

Comment: I added the semicolon but I still get the error?

Comment: You need a BEGIN between the WHILE and IF and the IF > ELSE IF chain needs to wrap any sections with more than one line in BEGIN/END statements. I think @RossBush has the idea though, I would move the FETCH NEXT to the end of the WHILE area and move the BEGIN above the first IF and it should be good.

Comment: Is this an academic exercise or a real world simulation? The reason I ask is because using a cursor here is not a good solution. This could be accomplished with a set based approach and it would be a LOT faster.

Answer (score 1):

so you have a few syntax issues and then some logic issues with the way your code is written.  You have the `FETCH NEXT` nested in an `IF` statement so the `WHILE` block would not actually select the next record unless `@status = 1`....

Organizing your code with indents and white space will help you dramatically to understand the logic and precedence of your steps.  You were missing a `BEGIN` for the cursor loop.

Also note that semicolon's for sql-server are not always necessary except in the case of THROW and Common Table Expressions the statements prior to those have to be terminated with a semicolon which is why you often see them written as `;WITH cte` as and `;THROW 51000,`...  I am sure there are other examples I am just giving a few.

Anyway, dump all of the If use a `case expression` which is much more geared for this type of operation build your string and then print it.

Also note, when you have a syntax error in the Results you can double click on it and it should bring you to the syntax error in question.

```
DECLARE

-- LOCAL VARIABLEs
@OrderId INT , @status TINYINT


--declare the cursor 
DECLARE mynamelist CURSOR STATIC FOR
    SELECT
       h.SalesOrderID,
       h.Status
    FROM
       Sales.SalesOrderHeader h

open mynamelist; 

FETCH NEXT FROM mynamelist INTO @status, @OrderId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(1000)
    SET @Message = 'Order Number:' + CAST(@OrderId as VARCHAR(10)) + 'Status:'
    SET @Message = @Message + CASE
          WHEN @status = 1 THEN 'Approved'
          WHEN @status = 3 THEN 'Backordered'
          WHEN @status = 4 THEN 'Rejected'
          WHEN @status = 5 THEN 'Shipped'
          ELSE 'Cancelled'
       END

    PRINT @Message;

    FETCH NEXT FROM mynamelist INTO @status, @OrderId

END

CLOSE nynamelist;

DEALLOCATE mynamelist;
```

Comment: When i execute it I get Order Number:5Status:Cancelled
Order Number:5Status:Cancelled
Order Number:5Status:Cancelled
Order Number:5Status:Cancelled
Order Number:5Status:Cancelled
Order Number:5Status:Cancelled
Order Number:5Status:Cancelled
Order Number:5Status:Cancelled
Order Number:5Status:Cancelled

Comment: And if you execute your select statement by itself what do you get?  All order Number 5's with status not in (1,3,4,5)?

Comment: I found my error, Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: your welcome glad to help. if my answer helped/answered please consider accepting it so others no you have figured out your issue and reputation points are awarded. cheers